# Why is $\vec{D}$ called displacement field and not $\vec{E}$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, terminology, polarization, dielectric

I'm repeating my electrodynamics knowledge and immediately had a very easy question which drives me crazy (and not a dupe, at least I didn't find a suitable answer, although many similar questions):

Consider an isolated capacitor with one positive and one negative charged plate, so that there is an electric field $\vec{E}$ between the plates. The corresponding number of field lines per unit area is $\vec{D} = \epsilon_0 \cdot \vec{E}$. Now a dielectric material is inserted between the plates.

What quantity stays constant and what decreases? I think $\vec{E}$ decreases because work is spend for the displacement of charges within the dielectric material, i.e. to polarize it. So many field lines from the one plate will not make it to the other plate but end on some dipole in the dielectric material. However, the number of field lines per unit area (which is $\vec{D}$) stays constant because for every field line from the positive plate that ends on the negative side of a dipole there is a new field line from the positive side of the same dipole to the negative plate.

So, if $\vec{E}$ is affected by the displacement of charges in the dielectric material (actually $\vec{E}$ is causing the displacement), but $\vec{D}$ is invariant.., why do we call $\vec{D}$ the displacement field and not $\vec{E}$?

Maybe it's just a name convention (which kills all discussion). So the real question is: Am I right with the behaviour explained above? If yes, I will simply accept the name convention, but would prefer some intuitive explanation why we call the quantity displacement which doesn't change...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an isolated capacitor, what stays constant is the total free charge on the capacitor plates. What happens to the E- and D-fields will depend exactly how the dielectric material is introduced and what portion of the volume between the plates is occupied by the dielectric.

Since D-field lines begin and end on free charges, the total number of D-field lines will be conserved. The number of E-field lines that begin/end on free charges on the plates *will also* be conserved, but the E-field in the dielectric will be weaker than in the "empty" capacitor because some of the E-field lines will terminate on polarisation charges at the surface of the dielectric and then new E-field lines will begin on opposing polarisation charges on the opposite surface of the dielectric. If necessary, the free charge on the plates will move to ensure that the electric field *parallel* to any interface between dielectric and vacuum between the plates is constant.

The origin of the term "displacement field" is perhaps best addressed in History of Science SE. I would think it derives from the fact that $\partial \vec{D}/\partial t$ is the displacement current density. However, I note that if the capacitor is not isolated and then uniformly filled with a dielectric, then it is the E-field that remains constant and the D-field that changes.

Comment: Perfect, you saved my weekend! That is actually the capacitor behaviour I expected. Many thanks!